# Is there a way to get a key for the title screen door?

Tags: the-room

On the title screen of [The Room](http://fireproofgames.com/the-room), there is a lock next to the doorknob with a covering that can be swiveled away, leading me to believe that there is some sort of key I can place in the lock.

Is there actually something to do on the title screen, or is it just for show?

I've beaten the game, and still haven't found anything to do with it. If it matters, I'm playing the android version released in the latest humble bundle.

Comment: I don't think you are meant to unlock that door. Maybe it'll be explained in the coming chapters.

Answer (score 2):

I am quite sure the fact that the lock can be swiveled away is simply an aesthetic element.

Considering the fact that the door is open, I don't think there is a lock to be found.

Also, if there was some kind of easter egg on the title screen, we'd be sure to hear about it after a quick search on the interwebs. 5 minutes of research on my part yielded nothing.

Don't worry I'm quite certain you're not missing anything. Just an educated guess.